# SAS Input: Integers Separated by Commas

Tags: sas

This seems incredibly basic, but I simply can't find the right informat in SAS to read in the kind of data I have, which looks like this:

```
9  Bittersweet                 #FD7C6E  (253, 124, 110)  48 1949
10  Black                      #000000  (0,0,0)          8 1903
```

I need to read in the values in parentheses into three separate numeric variables, and there's no informat I can find that simply "reads in numeric characters until it encounters a non-numeric character." The file is not completely comma-separated, more's the pity (whoever "designed" this file format should be shot, dead, buried, resurrected, and shot again!) The problem with the data in parentheses is that sometimes there is a space after a comma, and sometimes not. I've gotten the first number and the first set of characters after the number read in via column input, since the `#` is always in column 32. I've read in the six-digit hex value (just using character there).

Here is my MWE:

```
Data crayons;
    Infile 'path\crayons.dat' MISSOVER;
    Input crayon_number
          color_name $ 4-31
          hex_code   $ 33-38 @42
          red   3. @','
          green 3. @','
          blue  3. @')'
          pack_size
          year_issued
          year_retired;
Run;
```

The `Bittersweet` line is read in correctly, but not the `Black` line. (`year_retired` is blank for both of these - I'm not concerned about that.) In the `Black` line, I get the `hex_code` variable correctly, but nothing after that.

> So I guess the central question is this: how do I read in an integer of varying length that is guaranteed ***NOT*** to contain a comma, particularly when it is immediately followed by a comma?

Perhaps at a higher level: where can I go to find these sorts of things out? I have these questions about reading in dirty data, and I don't know where to go to find out. The SAS Language Reference is woefully inadequate for this, in my experience. If data fits into their neat little boxes, you're good to go. Anything outside of that, and their reference is useless.

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Are there always three values on every line? Do you have any other commas or parenthesis in the line or can you just ignore them?

Comment: No other commas or parentheses on a line. There are always three values inside the parentheses, which are RGB integers, but I want them in separate variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use list input with delimiters=' (,)'

```
Data crayons;
   infile cards dlm=' (,)' missover;
   Input crayon_number
          color_name &$28.
          hex_code $   
          red   
          green 
          blue  
          pack_size
          year_issued
          year_retired;
   list;
   cards;
9  Bittersweet                 #FD7C6E  (253, 124, 110)  48 1949
10  Black                      #000000  (0,0,0)          8 1903
```

Comment: Adding the columns for the `color_name` variable to your answer got me what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Your 2 lines of example data and your first attempt with at mix of line, column and formatted input modes suggests LIST input would be best.  &$28. would be a better choice in my opinion.

Comment: Well, you know what they say: "In theory, there's no difference between theory and practice, but in practice, there is." `&$28` didn't work, whereas adding the columns for `color_name` did.

Comment: @AdrianKeister You forgot the period for the $ format.  Should be &$28.  I did not fully appreciate you desire to be right.

Comment: I think when I tested it I included the period. I just copied your code exactly. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to read it in as a character as a whole field and use SCAN() later on.

Since you mention that the position is fixed, it sounds like you're reading a fixed width type file?

```
red = scan(orig_var, 1, "(,)");
green = scan(orig_var, 2, "(,)");
blue = scan(orig_var, 3, "(,)");
```